# stripping out (ascii armored) PGP blocks in text file

Tags: sed, grep, sh, pcregrep

given a file formatted as markdown occasionally interspersed with blocks of PGP, how can I strip out the PGP blocks using standard linux tools in a shell script?

The file looks like [this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sean9999/8d8cccb93f8ab877ffc2116eb2516324/raw/2692da72368625c66bc6640106262d10a3ba6f27/markup_example.md)

(I had to create a gist because of formatting issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed you can do that:

```
sed '/^-----BEGIN PGP/,/^-----END PGP/d' file
```

In short: you define a range of lines between two patterns `/pat1/,/pat2/` that are deleted (d).